# Admin for wrt54g v3.1 simply disappeared post-tomato WDS! How can I get back into Admin screen?

Tags: tomato, wrt54g, wds

I am at a complete loss. I picked up a WRT54G 3.1, installed Tomato 1.28, and went through the instructions here to setup WDS: http://www.polarcloud.com/tomatofaq#how_do_i_use_wds

As soon as I hit SAVE, I can no longer access the router, wired, wirelessly, or any other way shape or form. I'm sure i didn't change the IP address on the router (thus changing the admin local URL), I've tried going with HTTPS but was pretty certain that wasn't the issue anyway.

Right now, I've got a chunk of blue and grey plastic on my desk, and no extended network.

My plan was to use this to extend the Time Capsule network so I can plug my XBOX into the WRT54G in another room. In any event, if it were only network config I was dealing with, I'm sure I could figure it out, but how in the heck can I connect to the Tomato admin on the WRT54G now?

Any ideas certainly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing a hard reset, which will reset your Tomato router configuration back to its default settings.

Unplug the router, press the little reset button on the back, plug it back in, continue to hold the button for at least 30 seconds, and release.  You should now be able to access the admin interface at the default location (*http://192.168.0.1/*) and the default password (`admin`).  You will need to reconfigure all your settings as they were before, unless you saved a backup.